# Extract EPS file data for PGF plot

Tags: pgfplots, eps, matlab

For our project this semester we have to make a scientific paper and poster. To keep the poster nice and uniform we are using PGFplots for our graphs.

One problem though is that MATLAB Simulink can't give us the raw data, when simulating our complementary filter. We can only get a EPS-file.

EPS is at least still vector graphics, but it looks weird next to our PGF-graphs.

Is there a way fo extracting the raw data form the EPS-file, or is anyone experienced with Simulink and knows a way to get the raw data?

Comment: Without seeing your simulink model it would be hard to tell if you can or can't add an output port in for every variable you wish to have to data for. If you're able to have the data though, I'd recommend using [`matlab2tikz`](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz)

Comment: @mriisa first, collect the raw-simulated-data to the workspace, then export it to CSV. Finally, import the CSV data into pgfplots. This should solve your issue. Nevertheless, I think this question is `out-of-scope` for this site. But if it s 2d plot, go with Elad's suggestion. For 3d, the solution is not reliable.